# Merging ee.FeatureCollection for training data in PythonAPI

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, feature-collection

```
js_shpz = json.loads(geom.to_json())
shpz = ee.Geometry(ee.FeatureCollection(js_shpz).geometry())

fc = geojson.FeatureCollection(mrg)
img_clip = image.clip(shpz)
training_data = img_clip.sampleRegions(
                collection=fc,
                properties= ['LC'],
                scale= 30)
print(training_data);
```

This is the code I am using for PythonAPI for Google Earth Engine for making a LULC Map.
Here is the csv file https://gist.github.com/yajnab/e67af4cdfe789e8f42bb0414888a9ae4

I am trying to put that collection in collections for making the training data.
I am provided with a error Invalid GeoJSON Geometry
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
def to_feature(row):
    return ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry(json.loads(row['.geo'])), 
        {'LC': row['LC']}
    )

data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
    to_feature(row) 
    for i, row in data.iterrows()
])
```